# Seperate Number and Letter in a String

Tags: javascript, string

```
let input_string='L10M111.05K268.68V 265.42';

let output_string='L 10 M 111.05 K 268.68 V 265.42';
```

Input string above has both numbers and letters in it which I need to seperate them using space as shown in my output string.

May I know how to achieve this? Any help will be very appreciated :)

Comment: `'L10M111.05K268.68V 265.42'.match(/(\d+(\.\d+)?)|[a-zA-Z]+/g).join(' ')`

Answer (score 3):

One way to do it is to search the string for words (sequential letters) and numbers (digits, followed by an optional period and more digits), and ignore everything else. Then, with those matches, join them all on a single space. You can do that with:

```js
'L10M111.05K268.68V 265.42'.match(/(\d+(\.\d+)?)|[a-zA-Z]+/g).join(' ')
```

Comment: Fantastic....!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modified version that will also process negative numbers and numbers starting with a decimal point:

```js
const res='abc.4L10M_D-111.05K268.68V 265.42 Last-.75end-it-all'.replace(/ *(-?(\.\d+|\d+(\.\d+)?)) */g," $1 ").trim();

console.log(res);
```